# how to fix if an error occurs after downloading codeIgniter 3.1.1 in file index.php line 315

Tags: codeigniter

error after downloading codeIgniter 3.1.1 in file index.php line 315
Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\app_token_listrik\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

I tried checking the line with the error but it still couldn't, I hoped the error would disappear on the page